# vs code typescript became white in a project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using typescript, and suddenly all my project became white. The only thing Highlighted are the parenthesis. I have no idea if I pressed a shortcut or something.

Other language like css and html have proper color, but all my Typescript is now fully white.

Is there some setting to check ?

I tried

- change theme to Dark+
- clear editor history
- restart computer
  [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had something similar, downgrading the JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension to the previous version fixed it.

[image]

Comment: Helps me as well, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the issue is caused by the latest version(`v5.0.20221116`) of JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension. You can downgrade the extension to `v5.0.20221115` until they publish a fixed version.

Here is how to downgrade a VSCode extension:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_install-previous-versions