# Error about theme in VSCode, theme isn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I got an error about the theme when I was coding, the text in the file was all white. I have tried many ways like resetting extension theme or reinstalling extension but it still doesn't work. Help me please, thanks. [error color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoZsu.png)

Help me fix an error about the theme in vscode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471515/visual-studio-code-color-not-working-fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vs code typescript became white in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74469466/vs-code-typescript-became-white-in-a-project)